# Customize java script language, from code to code

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm confuse how to convert this code (code 1)

> ```
> $("<div/>").append($("<b/>").text("Duration: ")).append($("<span/>").text(e.media$group.yt$duration.seconds)).appendTo(div);
> ```

to display **Duration** correctly in **second**
that code only show `Duration: 4267`

I want to display like this `Duration: 2:9 (129 seconds)` but the example code different, because like this (code 2)

```
s += '<b>Duration:</b> ' + Math.floor(data.entry.media$group.yt$duration.seconds / 60) + ':' + (data.entry.media$group.yt$duration.seconds % 60) + ' (' + data.entry.media$group.yt$duration.seconds + ' seconds)<br/>';
```

How to change my code (code 1) to some thing display **Duration** in correctly? or in my word, how to convert code 2 to languange in code 1

Comment: Why don't you just replace `e.media$group.yt$duration.seconds` with variable s in your code 2? Code 1 seems haven do any calculations.

Comment: how to do that, i dont undestand with the code

Comment: You can see my answer below, I hope that can help.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this can do the job. You have to create a new date with that amount of milliseconds from the beginning of time (1st Jan 1970) and then get minutes seconds etc...

```
var date = new Date(129 * 1000);
var secs = date.getSeconds();
var minutes = date.getMinutes();
```

The code in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sfarsaci/zuMtj/) seems to be working

I've updated [your fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sfarsaci/Y8smG/4/) too

Comment: how i edit this code like you said 


   ` $("<div/>").append($("<b/>").text("Duration: ")).append($("<span/>").text(e.media$group.yt$duration.seconds)).appendTo(div);`

Comment: Assuming the duration is in $duration.seconds should be something like this `var date = new Date($duration.seconds* 1000);
var secs = date.getSeconds();
var minutes = date.getMinutes(); $("<div/>").append($("<b/>").text("Duration: ")).append($("<span/>").text(minutes + ":" + secs)).appendTo(div);`

Comment: still get confuse... :( here my customize code http://jsfiddle.net/trogie/Y8smG/2/

Answer (score 0):

This should do your tricks.

```
var duration=e.media$group.yt$duration.seconds;
var h=Math.floor(duration/3600);
var m=Math.floor(duration/60%60);
var s=Math.floor(duration%60);
var timestr=h+':'+m+':'+s+' ('+duration+' seconds)';

$("<div/>").append($("<b/>").text("Duration: ")).append($("<span/>").text(timestr)).appendTo(div);
```

Comment: actually i dont understand with it, please look my code http://jsfiddle.net/trogie/Y8smG/2/ i just want to edit my Duration in Javascript. can you help me?